# Delta-Wye transformer differential protection during external line to line faults

Tags: transformer, relay, high-voltage, power-engineering, distribution-network

[image: line to line fault behind D-Y transformer]

During these kind of line to line faults current flows in the faulted phases of the secondary and all phases of the primary as it is shown in the image. So now the currents in phase A are not equal to each other(even if you account for the transformation ratios of the power transformer and current transformers). How can a numerical differential relay figure out that this is an external fault and not trip? I could not find a discussion of this in Siemens, ABB, Schneider manuals.

Comment: What is the lightning arrow symbol on the b output mean to represent? What does this mean: *the currents in phase A are not equal*? i.e. not equal to what? What have *Siemens, ABB, Schneider manuals* got to do here? What are you mentioning them? Is there some relevance?

Comment: It represents a line to line fault. They are not equal to each other(even if you account for all the transformation ratios and phase shifts). Yes there is some relevance as they manufacture digital differential transformer protection relays

Comment: You do realize that any pictures you put into your question require attribution to the source you took them from. Also, do you realize that the picture is a Y-delta transformer and not delta-Y?

Answer (score 1):

Transformer differential protection is not comparing corresponding phase currents on each side of the bank, it is a comparison between an intentional combination of phase currents.

The figure below is from a set of my lecture notes on transformer protection.  The currents shown in red are the primary phase currents, those in green are the secondary currents to the relays.

You can see that the top differential relay only receives \$I_a\$ on its right-side input tap, and \$I_{a'}-I_{c'}\$ on its left-side input tap (both divided by their respective CT ratios).  So, external faults do not upset the differential balance.

This phase compensation (\$I_{a'}-I_{c'}\$) is done with delta connected CTs for electromechanical differential relays.  Numerical relays can do this subtraction internally so they can use wye CTs like I show below.

[image]

p.s.  I am only showing currents to the top differential.  You can easily fill in those going to the 2nd and 3rd differential elements.

Answer (score 0):

Sensing primary and secondary 3ph currents each must sum to be zero, and the differential is computed based on turns ratio and core losses. Otherwise, there may be a fault.  Yet CT's can give false readings when saturated by a fault either internal to a large power transformer or external and must be protected yet be able to detect tiny internal faults.  Also inrush currents from remanence and reclosure out-of-phase {from off to on} may mimic internal faults, so Numerical Differential Protection Algorithms are used for Power Transformers.

Many methods are used but the basic methods use detection of the harmonic distortion ratio which is higher in inrush and overvoltage than in fault conditions.

Computation methods may use AI Neural Networks, Fuzzy Logic and wavelets to protect the multi-million dollar power transformers.

Newer methods compute impedance changes with thresholds such as rising currents with lowering voltages on consecutive phases and cycles using dot products of measured results.  The differential current is calculated by subtracting the referred secondary current from the primary current. If the difference is above the threshold then the harmonic content is examined with logic to rule out an internal fault.